# AngularJS VS ExtJS

Tags: angularjs, extjs

After reading the tutorials for both technologies **AngularJS** makes the HTML code much more easy to read.

My only concern is that **AngularJS** does not provide a Desktop Environment in terms of controls like **ExtJS** isn't that right?

Or is it these days **ExtJS** a technology becoming deprecated?

Comment: related https://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/2iydoh/angular_vs_sencha/

Comment: quick note: Sencha is almost completely unknown by many developers out there... it may be for a good reason. p.s. now you have tools like [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) which makes the decision even easier

Comment: Sencha is a nightmare if you want to control your front end's appearance. The HTML it generates is an appalling mess, trying to make it responsive, branded or themed is close to impossible. As a responsive webapp designer and front end developer, Sencha is a dealbreaker for me. My advice - Dontcha !!!

Comment: I don't think this question should have been closed. People need answers, even if they are opinion-based, to have some direction from other experienced users to make decisions about which technology to learn or implement.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What exactly do you want to ask with the question?
The main difference between AngularJS and ExtJS in my opinion is, that AngularJS focuses mainly on being a MVC Framework, which doesn't offer any extended library-style functionality to design fancy user interfaces. ExtJS goes a step further, it also is a MVC framework at the core, but offers more than that lots of functionality, for example designing of a user interface (probably what you mean by "Desktop Environment" lookalike). Visit the sencha homepage to get a full overview of the built in functionality. Using ExtJS to build webapp, there shouldn't be much of a need to add any other libraries.

To answer your second question: I don't think that ExtJS becomes deprecated, it has an active development and this year version 5 of the framework was launched.

The question "Should I use AngularJS or ExtJS" depends on the style of the frameworks, whatever you prefer and on your requirements. There are lots of articles which you may view, they compare the two frameworks in a detailed way: http://www.techferry.com/articles/ExtJS-vs-AngularJS.html

If you want to create an application with an user interface that looks like a Desktop Environment, you could either user ExtJS or AngularJS + a library, which provides functionality to create such an user interface.

Comment: So I think I'll use AngularJS + a library because in EtxJS the code is not embedded in the html, so it's impossible to understand the pages!

Comment: When I started with ExtJS I also felt this was a disadvantage, that the HTML pages were not understandable. But now I feel it's merely something you have to get past. A complex application is easier to trace/debug with many organized ExtJS classes as opposed to the HTML files. Also, ExtJS classes allow easy reuse. Try that with HTML. Sure you can start including pages snippets and all. Been there done that. Once you get past your initial ExtJS resistance, you won't want to get back. Angular is much more basic. Ext offers much much much more. Who cares about the larger footprint anyway?

Comment: I have to agree with Lawrence here. "Understanding the page" isn't something you need to do anymore with ExtJS. Everything is in Javascript, you don't need to debug your HTML/CSS anymore as ExtJS takes care of everything for you. You only have to care about your javascript working or not. It's a different mentality, but I remember struggling and having to inspect my page at first. It quickly goes away as you understand how ExtJS really works.

Comment: "Who cares about the larger footprint anyway?" Wow, @lawrence with that attitude you definitely should go work for Adobe =)

Comment: rodrigo, "larger footprint" should be seen in the context as: "loading in 0.001 second vs 0.01 second." Even though one is 100 times faster than the other, will you suffer from it? Google is also 100 times faster than Yahoo and Bing. Is Bing now totally useless?  The graphics by Ext are simply 100 times better than those of Angular. Have a look at a full blown Ext grid including paging and all, and look at the one of Angular.  Who cares if your page loads 10ms faster when everything looks so much better? That's what I actually meant. No disrespect intended to anyone.

Comment: @Lawrence, could you please elaborate when you said "A complex application is easier to trace/debug with many organized ExtJS classes as opposed to the HTML files". How is embedding HTML in your javascript easier compared to separating your template or HTML code from your javascripts? There are reasons why JSP was created on top of servlets. There are reasons why we often prefer declarative language over procedural when presenting UI; it gives us a closer picture or idea of what structure we are trying to build.

Comment: If you read this carefully, it reads like an ad or a testimonial. I wonder if the near-anon user is actually a sencha employee

Comment: @supertonsky Developer doesn't embed HTML in JS with ExtJS...they simply declare via JS object that they want a button, textbox, grid, etc and ExtJS creates the HTML/CSS....